# Codename One Components losing style on Eclipse

Tags: css, codenameone

I am working on an app that uses the css plugin. The IDE is Eclipse.

After accessing the internal theme editor, theme.res, and making some small experimental changes (not related to background), most components have changed their background to white.

I have deleted and regenerated the theme.res file and disabled an re-enabled the css support, but to no avail.

How can I get the original styling back?

Thanks in advance.

--- EDITED ----

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new project, Bare Bone;
2. Add two buttons;
3. Add UIID to buttonTwo;
4. Style buttons One and Two in the theme editor;
5. Add material icon to button;;
6. Activate css support in CN1 - settings;
7. Style buttonTwo in theme.css;

(Code snippets)

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    FontImage image = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD_BOX, "", 5);

    Button buttonOne = new Button("Button One");
    Button buttonTwo = new Button("Button Two");

    buttonTwo.setUIID("ButtonTwo");
    buttonOne.setIcon(image);

    hi.add(buttonOne).add(buttonTwo);

    hi.show();
```

(CSS Style)

```
    ButtonTwo {

        color: red; 

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the build directory and the res file. This should remove caches that might still be there. If it's still happening then it's triggered by a subtle change in the css or it was a problem that was always there. It was just hidden by the caches

Comment: I have made a few tests in a new project. Not using css, but the internal theme editor. As soon as I add a material icon to a simple button, font color turns white and deleting the material icon won't bring the prior styling back. I have to add a new UIID to the button, to be able to make changes to the font color. But adding a material icon to one of the buttons makes all buttons lose their styles. Removing the material icon does not bring the style back. Nor does removing the build folder and the res file. Could this be a regression?

Comment: The problem with the styling seems to be limited to Eclipse, NetBeans is working ok.

Comment: I'm not sure how well CSS works on eclipse so it might be related to that. We support IntelliJ & NetBeans reasonably well but the build.xml on eclipse is a bit different. However, if the CSS build work it should work from there. Try deleting the bin directory too besides the build directory and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: deleting the bin directory kept the project from running... classNotFoundException ccs = Null

Comment: Try refreshing or manually triggering the build. You can try doing that by sending a build to the cloud

Comment: ok, tried that with two different apps. Unfortunately, the styling is still messy. No changes ...

Comment: Can you post a step by step process from hello world that would reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Shai, edited my post above, including proceedings a a new screenshot and code. The style appears to disfigure after adding a material icon and simultaneously styling a component in the theme editor and with css (did that for a test). The issue seems to be limited to Eclipse. Problem is that deactivating css support does not bring the original styling back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `build.xml` file in the text editor. Make sure it has the `-cn1-compile-css` target. If it doesn't disable and re-enable CSS, then refresh the file.

Assuming this is now in place, edit the target to add a fork statement in the java call. Specifically convert this line:

```
<java jar="${user.home}/.codenameone/designer_1.jar" failonerror="true">
```

To this:

```
<java jar="${user.home}/.codenameone/designer_1.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">
```

Comment: Now it works, thank you .. interestingly, the -cn1-compile-css target was not in the build.xml file the first time I activated the css support in a new project. I had to disable and re-enable the css support to have the line appear in the file.

Comment: I think there is a bug where the build.xml update from settings overrwrites the CSS settings. If you get a chance it would be great filing an issue on that, we probably also need to generate the fork code, I'm not sure if it's there.

Comment: Filed the issue today. Thanks for your support. Link to issue is : https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2653